# Combining AEAD with RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, authenticated-encryption

'Hybrid' encryption, where we combine symmetric encryption with public-key cryptography, is pretty 'tried and tested'.

To summarise, we generate a symmetric key and encrypt it using RSA. We would encrypt our data using the symmetric, and prefix it with the IV and encrypted key. You therefore need the private key from the RSA keypair to be able to decrypt the symmetric key and then decrypt the data using the symmetric key.

My question is about combining RSA with *autheticated* encryption, specifically AES in GCM mode. Are there any pitfalls, or any reasons this might be a bad idea?

Is it a good idea to include the IV and RSA-encrypted symmetric key in the additional data (to provide integrity for them), or should they simply be prefixed to the encrypted data?

Comment: What security properties do you want? Anyone who knows your public key can send you a message with a valid authentication tag.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Are you sure that's correct, as I don't see how that would work? The symmetric key used by AES would be randomly generated. It is only stored with the encrypted data after being RSA-encrypted.

Comment: "The symmetric key used by AES would be randomly generated" by anyone "who knows your public key".

Comment: @RickyDemer Ah, I see the problem now... doesn't the same problem exist for 'normal' hybrid cryposystems too? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but these don't pretend to be "authenticated". We actually have a weak kind of authentication, knowing that whoever sent your message actually knew the whole message, not only part of that. The classic solution would be to add an (asymmetric) signature to your message.

Comment: We only necessarily have that "weak authentication" if the core public key scheme is at least RCCA secure. For (standard) authentication the sender needs either a pre-established secret or access to a manual channel (eprint.iacr.org/2007/131.pdf). $\;\;$

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann while adding a signature would present a solution, I guess it also means there is no point in using AEAD over 'normal' encryption, since it is the signature that is providing the integrity and authenticity properties?

Comment: With a signature, there is no point, yes. Without a signature, AEAD only provides a kind of integrity check (i.e. whoever authored part of the message also authored the whole one). When you include another shared secret in the plaintext, an attacker can't forge the whole message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main pitfall is possibly thinking that it provides authentication.

The result is *still* a public key scheme.

It won't help to include the IV in the associated data, since

that is already covered by the *authenticated* part of AEAD.

Including the RSA-encrypted symmetric key in the associated data would help by making the

resulting hybrid encryption CCA2 secure even if the core public key scheme is only RCCA secure.

RCCA: [Relaxing Chosen-Ciphertext Security](http://eprint.iacr.org/2003/174)

Comment: I need to make the IV available *somehow*, whether it is prefixed to the data or stored in the associated data - is there any reason *not* to store it in the associated data?

Comment: That would take slightly more computation. $\:$

Comment: So my understanding is that it is pointless to combine AEAD with RSA, because anyone with your public key can create data that will be verified as 'authentic'. Using a digital signature would prevent that, but then it is the *signature* providing the authenticity propery, not AE - so you gain nothing from combining the two.

Comment: AEAD with some public key encryption is probably the best way to build $\hspace{2 in}$ public key encryption with associated data. $\:$